# How to remove table column in Active Record

Tags: ruby, activerecord, orm

I would like to remove column from the table by using Active record. Please find the below snippet

```
require "active_record"
require 'sqlite3'
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => 'sqlite3', :database => 'test_one')

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
 table_name = "AccountBean"
 primary_key = "process_id"
 remove_column "xxx" // I need this type of method to remove column "xxx" from accounts table
end
```

Is there any class method in ActiveRecord which satisfy this requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess ActiveRecord presumes that changes to structure shall be done using migrations.

If you really need to, you could use the same methods rails uses in migrations to e.g. remove a column - [like here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb#L381-L386)

I don't recommend this :)

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.remove_column("persons", "first_name")`

Within a class that would look something like:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
 table_name = "AccountBean"
 primary_key = "process_id"
 connection.remove_column(table_name, "xxx")
end
```

Comment: Yes, but using connection method  even though we know we are in table represented class (Account) is bit of odd

Comment: @pramod - Method `remove_column` is intended for migrations only, thus you can't expect to have a nice simple API to change your table structure from `ActiveRecord` models :)